# Issues with Moment and ChartJS Time Format Parsing

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, datetime-conversion

I am attempting to mimic a gannt chart format using ChartJS 2.9's floating bar feature.  So far I have managed to do something similar with a line chart and some creative bending of ChartJS but there were serious flaws with it and it was not functioning like I needed it to.

Here is what I have right now that works, which is just using a simple dataset with integers:

```js
var temp = '{ "EmpLst": {"0" : "No Name","1" : "No Name2"},"dateData" : [{"x": "2021-1-6", "y": "2021-2-16"},{"x": "2021-1-31", "y": "2021-5-19"},{"x": "2020-11-2", "y": "2020-12-16"},{"x": "2020-12-20", "y": "2021-1-7"}]}';

var parsedJSon = JSON.parse(temp);
var empNames = Object.values(parsedJSon.EmpLst);


var data = {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: empNames,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'data',
      data: [
        [-3, 0],
        [1, 4]
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
    }, {
      label: 'data',
      data: [
        [1, 3],
        [6, 8]
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
    }
  }
};


var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('deviceOnChart').getContext('2d'), data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartTarget" style="height: 160px; width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="deviceOnChart" width="600" height="160" style="display: block; height: 160px; width: 600px;"></canvas>
  <div style="opacity:0;" class="chartTooltip center">
  </div>
</div>
```

Well, true to fashion, I somehow fixed my initial issue.  Now I can't get the x axes values for format.  Here is the code I have now below.  I believe, based on the ChartJS docs, that I have the time object set up correctly and I included all of the displayFormat options.

Have spent a good deal of time writing this question looking for something I may have missed data-wise as to why the labels won't format.

```js
var temp = '{ "EmpLst": {"0" : "No Name","1" : "No Name2"},"dateData" : [{"x": "2021-01-06", "y": "2021-02-16"},{"x": "2021-01-31", "y": "2021-05-19"},{"x": "2020-11-2", "y": "2020-12-16"},{"x": "2020-12-20", "y": "2021-01-07"}]}';

var parsedJSon = JSON.parse(temp);
var empNames = Object.values(parsedJSon.EmpLst);
var dateData = Object.values(parsedJSon.dateData);

var dataSets = [];

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < dateData.length; i1++) {
  dataSets.push({
    label: 'data',
    data: [
      [moment(dateData[i1].x, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(dateData[i1].y, 'YYYY-MM-DD')],
      [moment(dateData[i1 + 1].x, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), moment(dateData[i1 + 1].y, 'YYYY-MM-DD')]
    ],
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
  });

  i1++
}


var data = {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: empNames,
    datasets: dataSets
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
    },
    scales:{
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'month',
        displayFormats: {
          millisecond: 'MMM YY',
          second: 'MMM YY',
          minute: 'MMM YY',
          hour: 'MMM YY',
          day: 'MMM YY',
          week: 'MMM YY',
          month: 'MMM YY',
          quarter: 'MMM YY',
          year: 'MMM YY'
        }
      },
      ticks: {
        min: moment('2020-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        max: moment('2021-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
      },
    }],
  }
  }
};


var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('deviceOnChart').getContext('2d'), data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartTarget" style="height: 160px; width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="deviceOnChart" width="600" height="160" style="display: block; height: 160px; width: 600px;"></canvas>
  <div style="opacity:0;" class="chartTooltip center">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am probably over looking something but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, huge doh moment.  I forgot to add the xAxes object inside of scales......  Works!