# Chartjs: Moment and ChartJS Time Format Parsing

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, chart.js3, chart.jsv3

I need to make a bar chart using the time format, I started this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931303/issues-with-moment-and-chartjs-time-format-parsing) as a base but the library version is old and I need to use the new one but it is not working, can someone help me?

Values must be in hours:minutes:second timeframe.

here is the code so far
here is the code so far
here is the code so far
here is the code so far
here is the code so far

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js">        </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-adapter-moment/1.0.0/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="chartTarget" style="height: 160px; width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="deviceOnChart" width="600" height="160" style="display: block; height: 160px; width: 600px;"></canvas>
  <div style="opacity:0;" class="chartTooltip center">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
var temp = '{ "EmpLst": {"0" : "Parado","1" : "A pé"},"dateData" : [{"x": "07:00:00", "y": "09:10:00"},{"x": "08:00:00", "y": "08:10:00"}]}';

var parsedJSon = JSON.parse(temp);
var empNames = Object.values(parsedJSon.EmpLst);
var dateData = Object.values(parsedJSon.dateData);

var dataSets = [];

for (var i1 = 0; i1 < dateData.length; i1++) {
  dataSets.push({
    label: 'data',
    data: [
      [moment(dateData[i1].x, 'h:mm:ss'), moment(dateData[i1].y, 'h:mm:ss')],
      [moment(dateData[i1 + 1].x, 'h:mm:ss'), moment(dateData[i1 + 1].y, 'h:mm:ss')]
    ],
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
  });

  i1++
}
console.log(Date.parse(dataSets[0].data[0][0]._d))

var data = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: empNames,
    datasets: dataSets
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
    },
    scales: {
              x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                 unit: 'hour',
                  displayFormats: {
                    hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
                  },
                  tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
                  ticks:{
                min: moment('00:00:00', 'h:mm:ss'),
                max: moment('23:59:59', 'h:mm:ss'),
                },
                }
              }
            }
  }
};


var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('deviceOnChart').getContext('2d'), data);
</script>
```

this is what i want
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [time axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html), no need to parse the dates yourself. Simply define `time.parser` and let Chart.js do it's job. According to [3.x Migration Guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html), a few other things need also to be changed to make it work with Chart.js v3.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-adapter-moment/1.0.0/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>

  <div id="chartTarget" style="height: 160px; width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="deviceOnChart" width="600" height="160" style="display: block; height: 160px; width: 600px;"></canvas>
    <div style="opacity:0;" class="chartTooltip center">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
<script>
  var temp = '{ "EmpLst": {"0" : "Parado","1" : "A pé"},"dateData" : [{"x": "07:00:00", "y": "09:10:00"},{"x": "08:00:00", "y": "08:10:00"}]}';

  var parsedJSon = JSON.parse(temp);
  var empNames = Object.values(parsedJSon.EmpLst);
  var dateData = Object.values(parsedJSon.dateData).map(o => [o.x, o.y]);

  var dataSets = [{
    label: 'data',
    data: dateData,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
  }];

  var data = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: empNames,
      datasets: dataSets
    },
    options: {
      indexAxis: 'y',
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
        },
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            label: ctx => {
              const v = ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex];
              return v[0] + ' - ' + v[1];           
            }
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            parser: 'h:mm:ss',
            unit: 'hour',
            displayFormats: {
              hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
            }
          },
          min: '00:00:00',
          max: '24:00:00'
        }
      }
    }
  };


  var chart = new Chart('deviceOnChart', data);
</script>
```